# No internet access with self hosted VPN

Tags: vpn, ip, virtual-machines, wireguard

I setup a Wireguard VPN server on a Google Cloud VM but when connecting to it with the iOS client (running latest OS and app) nothing loads via the internet when the VPN is on (no browsing, emails, social media, etc), as if I don’t have an internet connection. What could be causing this, or how can I troubleshoot? Note: I am a beginner, and apologize if I am using incorrect terminology, feel free to correct me.

EDIT: Here is the configuration file (wg0.conf):

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.0.0.1/24
SaveConfig = true
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ens4 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o ens4 -j MASQUERADE
ListenPort = 51820
PrivateKey = *
```

EDIT: Here is a screenshot of the client app info: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KtVIs.jpg)

Comment: Could you please post the wireguard configuration?

Comment: @FRALEWHALE is it not there? I posted the wg0.conf file. Is that not the right one?

Answer (score 0):

would you please add the configuration of Wireguard here, then it is easier to analyze this. There could be several causes, like the DNS or the firewall rules. Please don't forget to hide all relevant information from your configuration

Comment: I added the config to the question @Cyanmodex9